# Restart ajax object with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a code like this:

```
object1 = $.ajax({
..
..
});
```

In the event of error I want to be able to restart the ajax, for example, if the connection of the user drops I want to be able to call the same ajax again without having to make $.ajax(.....). Is it possible to do something like:

```
object1.restart();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

put it in a function:

```
function callAjax() {
  $.ajax({
  ..
  ..
 });
```

Then its like `callAjax()` if theres an error..

Comment: the problem is that I have too many variables that would have to be saved in order to reuse it like you proposed. I cant believe there is no other way to reuse an ajax object after using it.

Comment: does the page reload or something? can you post whole ajax object? If you place it in one function, where does the variables change?

Answer (score 0):

That is easy, and jQuery allows you to do that inside an Ajax request. Have a look

```
$.ajax({
  /* full ajax body */
  url: 'page.html',
  data: 'if-any',
  success: function () {
    /* show that ajax request has finished */
  },
  error: function () {
    /* restart the ajax request, by re executing the function */
  }
});
```

You can try this:

```
function ajax_request () {
   $.ajax({
      /* full ajax body */
      url: 'page.html',
      data: 'if-any',
      success: function () {
         /* show that ajax request has finished */
      },
      error: function () {
         ajax_request(); // using this, you can re execute the function
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) is a potential candidate here,

for eg.

```
var object1 = $.ajax({
..
..
});


$.when(object1).fail(object1);
```